# How to improve performance of dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-performance

Gather schema stats took 16.30 hours using below blocks.
Is there any way to improve performance?

```
begin
   dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(
      ownname          => 'SCHEMA_NAME',
      estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size,
      method_opt       => 'for all columns size AUTO',
      cascade          => true, 
      degree           => 16
   );
end;
```

This  activity is performed once per week, but waiting 16 hours is not ok for users.

My Oracle db is version 11.2.0 and there are a few big partition tables in the schema, where  data insertion/deletion happen frequently.

Comment: Are you using incremental stats for the partitioned tables?

Comment: By default Oracle gathers the statistics automatically. Usually there is no need to trigger them manually. Did you check `LAST_ANALYZED` in `ALL_TABLES` and `ALL_TAB_PARTITIONS` view if this automatic collection does not fulfill your needs?

Comment: William ,I  check the  LAST_ANALYZED field of  few partition table it was sysdate-7 days.I am not sure  how do we take  incremental stats of  partitioned tables.Please guide me the steps for optimum  time  effective ways,so that even if any further data increases inthose partition table we no need to bother about time consumption of gather stats jobs.

Answer (score 2):

*Consider an extra parameter `options` with `GATHER AUTO` value between `ownname` and `estimate_percent` to collect statistics for only tables with no statistics or with more than 10% row changes to reduce the period of time, by the way keep `estimate_percent` parameter as `dbms_stats.auto_sample_size` since the database estimates the value automatically for you:*

```
begin
   dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats(
      ownname          => 'SCHEMA_NAME',
      options          => 'GATHER AUTO',
      estimate_percent => dbms_stats.auto_sample_size,
      method_opt       => 'for all columns size AUTO',
      cascade          => true, 
      degree           => 16
   );
end;
/
```

Comment: Thank you Barbaros. Only option parameter need to modify or  some other parameter  like  degree of  parallelism  also need to be modify,Considering there are some partition table involved on it.

Comment: @Santu. you're welcome. The value 16 seems excessively large enough assuming for a DBMS of a mid-type, perhaps a huge type enterprise. Moreover, You can switch `GATHER EMPTY` for one week (to calculate only the statistics of the tables with no stats) and `GATHER STALE` for one week (to calculate only the statistics of the tables with more than 10% row changes) to reduce the duration of the operation more.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need always to recalculate stats for the entire schema? You can perform gather stats also for single tables or just partitions and even for single columns. Limit gather stats to objects where data has been changed **significantly**.

It does not make any sense to gather stats on tables/partitions when there was no change in the data.

Comment: Its  very difficult  to  identify  what are the table where data are changed always.So we gather  stats  for entire schema in weekly basis. Do you mean the gather stats of partition tables  should be done separately before performs  gather schema statistices.

Comment: I think that you should know your application that well that you can spot which data are frequently changing.

Comment: ,Thanks for the comments,I noticed there are nearly 50 accounting partition table where data manipulation done frequently,These big tables are taking huge time nearly 13 hr and remaining 1500 tables took only 3.5 hrs.Please  advice the optimum way to gather entire schema stats or any other approach we need to adopt.